# Simple Frameworks for Displaying Bitmaps and Handling Button Presses

Tags: c++, user-interface, graphics, bitmap

We have a set of applications that basically display a bunch of bitmaps and text, then allow user to press "buttons" (certain bitmaps) that cause actions to occur.

We currently have these implemented using DirectX and a bunch of code to place the bitmaps and handle the button-presses.  But we'd like to have the following features:

- portable to Linux
- some sort of "editor" that would allow us to lay out screens without hard-coding locations of elements in code
- animation
- we need to be able to overlay video
- not resource intensive (these terminals don't have a lot of memory or CPU)
- we're currently using C++, so management would prefer that, but other languages would be considered
- We'd prefer a free, open-source solution, but would be willing to buy something if it is not too expensive.  (We have a couple dozen developers, and tens of thousands of terminals deployed.)

We don't like the common GUI toolkits or widgets.  We want something that has more of the look of a game than of a dialog box.

Any suggestions for off-the-shelf stuff we could use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe the way to go is something like [Clutter](http://clutter-project.org/) or [Allegro](http://www.allegro.cc/). If you check in this [article](http://arstechnica.com/news.ars/post/20080604-hands-on-with-the-ubuntu-netbook-remix.html) at ArsTechnica what they are using Clutter for, you might get an idea how to use it. I don't know for sure if it works on Windows, but I'm pretty sure it does, considering it only depends on libraries that are supported under Windows.

Answer (score 0):

You could try [wxWidgets](http://www.wxwidgets.org/) (it has wxBitmapButton) or try to implement your own solution using [SDL](http://www.libsdl.org/) for all of the graphics.

Answer (score 0):

"We don't like the common GUI toolkits or widgets. We want something that has more of the look of a game than of a dialog box."

You realize that Trolltech's QT has a style sheet language for widgets?  Take a look at their white paper, specifically page 60

http://trolltech.com/pdf/qt43-whitepaper-us.pdf

Going over your other requirements:

- portable to Linux

Yes.  Also supports Windows, Mac, and embedded environments.

- some sort of "editor" that would allow us to lay out screens without hard-coding locations of elements in code

Qt's Designer is a very nice tool.  I use it all the time.

- animation

Qt supports this.

- we need to be able to overlay video

Qt supports this.

- not resource intensive (these terminals don't have a lot of memory or CPU)

This might be the fly in the ointment.  You could check out Qt's embedded option.  I've never used that myself.

- we're currently using C++, so management would prefer that, but other languages would be considered

Qt is for C++ and works with all major compilers.

- We'd prefer a free, open-source solution, but would be willing to buy something if it is not too expensive. (We have a couple dozen developers, and tens of thousands of terminals deployed.)

Qt has both open-source and closed source options.